# How to output the csv file (Single different files) in one location to different folders created newly based on csv file name?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python scripting and stackoverflow community.
I am working on a task where I need to read data in a csv file.
The csv file contains data covering 110 rows from 0 to 110 rows. I need to read data in each row and change it in specific format arrangement (shown in coding tried below).
Then output the arranged data into new .csv file (output file).
So each row data to be read, modified and output that single row as .csv file..Likewise for 110 rows.

For now, I am able to read the data from the input .csv file and modify the data into required format and output each row data into seperate .csv files.
But I am able to output the csv files in one (same location) - the Working directory location (wdir) in python.

But I need to output each .csv file to newly created folders based on their .csv filename.
example: "1.csv file need to output to newly created folder named 1".. Likewise for all 110 .csv file..

So how to achieve this?? Please let me know..

#The Scripting I have done till now (Sorry if it is not correct..just a beginner)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'Filename.csv')
datab = pd.read_csv(r'Filename2.csv')
i=-1
while i<110:
      i= i+1
      path= "users\destination"
      os.makedirs (path + str(i))
      rowa = (data.loc[[i],:]
      rowb = (datab.loc[[i],:]
      rowa.loc[i,'S.No'] = 'POINT'
      rowb.loc[i,'S.No'] = 'POINT'
      rowa['ID'] = 1
      rowb['ID'] = 2
      rowa['value'] = ' '
      rowb['value'] = ' '
      rowa=rowa(['S.No','ID','value','A','B','C'])
      rowb=rowb(['S.No','ID','value','A','B','C'])
      print(rowa)
      print(rowb)
      rowa.to_csv('output'+str(i)+'.csv',header=False,index=False)
      rowb.to_csv('output'+str(i)+'.csv',mode='a',header=False,index=False)
```

Thanks in advance for everyone for helping me out with this..